# Share your sound design innuendos

Tags: humor, sound-design

Over the summer, while working a rehearsal, I decided to tweet a bunch of one liners relating to sound design with a somewhat dirty connotation.  Mine are below.  Please share any others you can think of!

- Are you XLRge?
- I'll send your outputs to my inputs.
- Ready for a 16 input mixer?
- Time to open up the patch bay.
- Gain down, slider up, that's the way we like to...
- Give those peaks some compression!
- Five prongs but only three holes.
- If you keep belting I might just have to ride you all night long.
- Don't mess with your face tape and I'll turn you on and push your buttons

Comment: And the purpose of this is...?

Comment: @Utopia "It's just a bit of humor bud, what are you a bolshevik or something?" lol sorry I just wanted to quote that..

Comment: @Utopia Promoting a sense of community, making people laugh, and seeing if anyone has anything to add.

Comment: This is sort of ironic because I've got a thing going with a close friend and sound design colleague based on mom jokes involving audio innuendos. Maybe I'll post a couple in this thread later if the thread reaches a comfortable state. 